# Erlang error handling philosophy - case vs throw

Tags: exception, error-handling, erlang

I'm writing a REST service in Erlang and need to verify the received data before passing it to other internal functions for further processing; in order to do that, I'm currently using nested `case` expressions like this:

```
case all_args_defined(Args) of
    true ->
        ActionSuccess = action(Args),

        case ActionSuccess of
            {ok, _} -> ...;
            {fail, reason} -> {fail, reason}
        end,
    _ ->
        {fail, "args not defined"}
end,
...
```

I realize this is kind of ugly, but this way I can provide detailed error messages. Additionally, I don't think the usual *make it crash* philosophy is applicable here - I don't want my REST service to crash and be restarted every time somebody throws invalid arguments at it.

However, I'm considering abandoning all those `cases` in favor of an umbrella `try/catch` block catching any `badmatch` errors - would this work?

```
fun() ->
    true = all_args_defined(Args),
    {ok, _} = action(Args).

%% somewhere else
catch fun().
```

Comment: Just a comment on the "let it crash" philosophy: If you're writing code that in itself cannot do anything sensible with the error (like the code for your individual actions), you should program for the success case and just let it crash if something is not right. This keeps the code short and focused. However, at some points, you will want to handle errors - like in a supervisor, or in your REST receive-execute-reply loop. Then you set things up with links or try/catch so that the errors are propagated to that point and handled there and only there.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense - I'm just too exception damaged from other... languages, so I try to avoid them when possible :) Erlang has a pretty sensible approach to exceptions though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since what you want to achieve is error reporting, you should structure the thing around the execution of actions and reporting of the result. Perhaps something like this:

```
  execute(Action, Args) ->
    try
      check_args(Args),
      Result = action(Action, Args),
      send_result(Result)
    catch
      throw:{fail, Reason} ->
        report_error(Reason);
      ExceptionClass:Term ->
        %% catch-all for all other unexpected exceptions
        Trace = erlang:get_stacktrace(),
        report_error({crash, ExceptionClass, Term, Trace})
    end.

  %% all of these throw {fail, Reason} if they detect something fishy
  %% and otherwise they return some value as result (or just crash)
  action(foo, [X1, X2]) -> ...;
  action(foo, Args) -> throw({fail, {bad_arity, foo, 2, Args}});
  action(...) -> ...

  %% this handles the formatting of all possible errors 
  report_error({bad_arity, Action, Arity, Args}) ->
    send_error(io_lib:format("wrong number of arguments for ~w: "
                             "expected ~w, but got ~w",
                             [Action, Arity, length(Args)]));
  report_error(...) -> ...;
  report_error({crash, Class, Term, Trace}) ->
    send_error(io_lib:format("internal error: "
                             "~w:~w~nstacktrace:~n~p~n",
                             [Class, Term, Trace])).
```

Comment: Nice idea matching the exception tuples! However, how would you handle a throw from a `gen_server`? For example, a `find/1` function in a `gen_server` throwing an exception because of an invalid search term would destroy the `gen_server` state, right? Is this better handled by pattern matching on the calling site and catching `badmatch`?

Comment: You could put the same kind of umbrella try/catch in each of the handle_cast/handle_call/handle_info callbacks, so that the server doesn't crash unless something really unexpected happens, and in all other cases, it will just send a reply stating that an error occurred (or log that it happened, for casts).

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem while developing an application that create users.

I first come with a solution like this:

```erlang
insert() ->
    try
        check_1(), % the check functions throw an exception on error.
        check_2(),
        check_3(),
        do_insert()
    catch
        throw:Error1 ->
            handle_error_1();
        throw:Error2 ->
            handle_error_2();
        _:Error ->
            internal_error()
    end.
```

The problem with this solution is that you lose the stack trace with the try...catch block.
Instead of this, a better solution is:

```erlang
insert() ->
    case catch execute() of
        ok -> all_ok;
        {FuncName, Error} ->
            handle_error(FuncName, Error);
        {'EXIT', Error} ->
            internal_error(Error)
    end.

execute() ->
    check_1(), % the check functions throw an exception on error.
    check_2(),
    check_3(),
    do_insert().
```

This way you have the full error stack on Error.

Comment: I think RichardC's solution simplifies this even more :)

Comment: The first version is the easiest and best satisfies the original question. The idea was not to generate an error but to return a suitable error value, and I don't think the stacktrace is that important. If you wanted to generate errors that would be different, but then you could use `erlang:get_stacktrace()`.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced exactly the same question when writing my own REST services.

Let's start with the philosophy:

I like to think of my applications like a box. On the inside of the box are all of the parts I built and have direct control over. If something breaks here, it's my fault, it should crash, and I should read about it in an error log. On the edge of the box are all of the connection points to the outside world - these are not to be trusted. I avoid exception handling in the inside parts and use it as needed for the outer edge.

On similar projects I have worked on:

I usually have about a dozen checks on the user input. If something looks bad, I log it and return an error to the user. Having a stack trace isn't particularly meaningful to me - if the user forgot a parameter there is nothing in my code to hunt down and fix. I'd rather see a text log that says something like: “at 17:35, user X accessed path Y but was missing parameter Z”.

I organize my checks into functions that return `ok` or `{error, string()}`. The main function just iterates over the checks and returns `ok` if they all pass, otherwise it returns the first error, which is then logged. Inside of my check functions I use exception handling as needed because I can't possibly consider all of the ways users can screw up.

As suggested by my colleagues, you can alternatively have each check throw an exception instead of using a tuple.

As for your implementation, I think your idea of using a single exception handler is a good one if you only have the single check. If you end up needing more checks you may want to implement something like I described so that you can have more specific logging.

Comment: Would RichardC's pattern-matching exception code work in your case? I.e. what if you threw `{fail, ...}` from your checks and report the errors in a single umbrella (pattern matching) `catch` block? What advantages do you have by using return values instead of exceptions?

Comment: Using a single umbrella catch and having each check potentially throw a {fail, Reason} is, I think, functionally the same as the approach I mentioned. You may want to experiment and see which seems more readable to you. The main point that I want to convey is that if you have multiple checks, you'll probably want them logged in a human-readable way - e.g. have a message for each type of error and write it to a text file (as opposed to a stack trace in an error log).